# Redirect Loop only in Safari - WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

I hope someone can help.

I'm facing a very strange situation.

A friend of mine has a WordPress site. He made the switch to HTTPS. (https://kaza-hogar.com/)
No problem at the beginning.
Now Safari pages are not loading due to a redirect loop.
What is strange is that in Chrome there is no problem.
And checking with various online tools like redirect-checker.org ... the connection seems to be fine. No redirection at all ... or eventually just one redirection: HTTP -> 301 -> HTTPS.

The .htaccess file has this rule in the main site folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

If I remove the above code for redirection of course everything loads fine in Safari too.

Do have any idea why this is happening just in Safari?

Comment: I saw similar issue on lates iphone+safari, site was running on https, guy type address with http, site redirects to https then safari forces back to http, simple fix was type address with https,  safari is new IE nowadays

Comment: "due to a redirect loop" - What is the nature of the redirect loop? What it is redirecting from/to, etc.? What are the HTTP response codes being reported on each response?

Comment: There would seem to be "something else" that is (also?) triggering canonical redirects. If I request `http://www.example.com/` there is a single redirect to `https://example.com/` - the rule you've posted would not do that since it preserves the `HTTP_HOST`. So, what is triggering that redirect? (Please include your complete `.htaccess` file.)

Comment: "or **eventually** just one redirection: HTTP -> 301 -> HTTP." - Why "eventually"? Is there a delay or something? And shouldn't that be HTTP**S** as the final destination?

Comment: First of all thank you @MrWhite for the questions.
Redirect is done by .htaccess file to send traffic from HTTP to HTTPS. 

If I try on a service like [https://wheregoes.com](https://wheregoes.com/trace/20222996972/) the HTTP codes are ok ... the trace is very simple:

https://kaza-hogar.com -> HTTP CODE 200 -> no reditect 
http://kaza-hogar.com -> HTTP CODE 301 -> https://kaza-hogar.com -> HTTP CODE 200 -> 1 redirect
Still Safari (only Safari) says there is an error loop: "Safari cannot follow more 20 redirects."